# Documents in a Publishing Page library - any disadvantages?

Tags: document-library, publishing-page

I know that the goal makes many people flinch, but we want to have both HTML elements and regular documents ( such as PDF and PPT files ) in the same library. It seems to me now a"Document" content type to the Publishing Page library ( "Pages" ) might take us to where we want to go. Are there any disadvantages with having documents in a Publishing Page library?

It works the other way around (HTML content in Doc Lib), by adding a"Basic Page" content type Document Library, but this requires inserting the HTML in a Page Content column of each element - far from the simplicity of creating new publishing pages and editing these directly.

For those who wonder why I am going down this path: The main advantage is that we can then instantly search within both the text content and the documents using the very nifty jQuery DataTables. It's quicker to load, easier to maintain and set up and less complicated than combining data in SharePoint designer, creating complex content queries or custom lookup mechanisms combined with XLST customizations.

Comment: In my experience, if you have a working solution that meets your needs, that far outweighs any theoretical disadvantage that isn't affecting you right now. Publishing libraries have the same limits and constraints as any other doc lib.

Comment: Thank you, this solution has been working very well so far.